# JSON Data not loading on ng-init on div, it's loading on ng-click on button

Tags: angularjs

I have data attached to $scope object in controller, just like this

```
           $scope.result = [];
  $scope.jsonData = function () {
            var result = [];
            var keys = $scope.data[0];

            for (var i = 1; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
                var item = {};
                item[keys[0]] = $scope.data[i][0];
                item[keys[1]] = $scope.data[i][1];
                item[keys[2]] = $scope.data[i][2];
                 $scope.result.push(item);
            }
            console.log($scope.result);
 };
```

I am able to access this data only while clicking button in HTML using ng-click directive

```
<button ng-click="jsonData()">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in result">
                        <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Age}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Address}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </button>
```

However, I am unable to access json data using ng-init directive. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
<div ng-init="jsonData()">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in result">
                        <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Age}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Address}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: How are you filling $scope.data? Guessing ng-init is running before $scope.data is ready.

Comment: How to run ng-init after $scope.data is ready ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ng-init this way?  Take a look at the documentation:

[ng-init documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

This doesn't look like a valid use case for ng-init unless there is more code to your controller I cannot see.

I would get rid of the ng-init on your div and just run the function directly in your controller by calling:

```
$scope.jsonData();
```

right after you define the function. Like this:

```
$scope.result = [];
$scope.jsonData = function () {
        var result = [];
        var keys = $scope.data[0];

        for (var i = 1; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
            var item = {};
            item[keys[0]] = $scope.data[i][0];
            item[keys[1]] = $scope.data[i][1];
            item[keys[2]] = $scope.data[i][2];
             $scope.result.push(item);
        }
        console.log($scope.result);
}; 
$scope.jsonData();
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause of the problem is that the `ng-init` directive is executing before the data arrives from the server.

In the controller, *chain* from the promise that puts the data on scope:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
}).then(function() {
    $scope.jsonData();
});
```

In an MV* framework, the controller creates the model and then the framework maps the model to the DOM. The framework then collects events from the user and informs the controller which then updates the model.

Having the DOM initiate, by `ng-init`, a change to the model is a violation of the [ZEN of Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction#the-zen-of-angularjs).

It is a very good idea to decouple DOM manipulation from app logic. This dramatically improves the testability of the code. By coupling the app sequencing and logic to the `ng-init` directive, the code becomes fragile, difficult to test, hard to maintain, and error prone.